# Play sound in javascript

Tags: javascript, mp3

So I've put my sound file in a sub folder of my code directory and whenever I try to play it, it says it can't find it.

Here's my code:

```
PlaySound = function () {
    var audio = new Audio('~/Content/Sound/Down.mp3');
    audio.loop = false;
    audio.play(); 
}
```

Anyone know why?

This is the error I get when I inspect:

```
GET http://localhost:5/~/Content/Sound/Down.mp3 
localhost/:1 Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: Failed to load 
because no supported source was found.
```

Comment: Can you open the file directly in the browser?

Comment: Is the _Content_ folder in the web document root (ie `wwwdata` or something similar)?

Comment: can you access `http://localhost:5/~/Content/Sound/Down.mp3` from your browser? `~` means that you start at your home directory

Comment: give your file path correctly

Comment: Not sure @Halcyon, but it's in my code. I've put multiple pictures another folder in code which works fine, but this one, it can't read it, I've taken the pictures from the same file path but from pictures folder.

Answer (score 9):

Put the soundfile in the *same* directory that your HTML file is in.

after that, this code should not give you any errors:

```
PlaySound = function () {
    var audio = new Audio('Down.mp3');
    audio.loop = false;
    audio.play(); 
}
```

Your Broswer has to be able to access the Audio file, so if you visit `http://localhost:5/~/Content/Sound/Down.mp3`, it should actually open the file

Answer (score 1):

Try giving the absolute path instead of relative one.

use: 
    `./Content/Sound/Down.mp3`

or this: 
   `/Content/Sound/Down.mp3`

Answer (score 0):

why don't you use the html5 audio tag

```
<audio controls>
  <source src="sample.ogg" type="audio/ogg">
  <source src="sample.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
</audio>
```

Comment: This does not _answer_ the question. You could perhaps post it as a comment.

Comment: i don't have that much privileges to comment on question

Comment: why don't you try absolute path instead of relative path

Answer (score 0):

I think the answer is you can't play an audio before the user interact with the window, you need to do PlaySound function clickable in button or something like that

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).